# Initialize a class having another class object as member variable

Tags: java

This is my first class:

```
package trickycorejava;

public class InnerClass {
    int id;
    oneClass oneClass;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public trickycorejava.oneClass getOneClass() {
        return oneClass;
    }

    public void setOneClass(trickycorejava.oneClass oneClass) {
        this.oneClass = oneClass;
    }

    public InnerClass(int id, trickycorejava.oneClass oneClass) {
        this.id = id;
        this.oneClass = oneClass;
    }
    public InnerClass(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class oneClass {
    private String name;

     public String getName() {
        return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is the class where the main method exists, observe that the package is different:

```
package trickycorejava.constructor;

import trickycorejava.InnerClass;

public class InnerClassTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InnerClass innerClass = new InnerClass(1);
    }

}
```

How can I initialize the InnerClass with constructor in this case? If I use

`InnerClass innerClass = new InnerClass(1, new oneClass("Test"));`

I get the error that `oneClass` is not public cannot be access from outside package.

Comment: Move `oneClass` in its own file `oneClass.java` (in the same package/folder as `InnerClass.java`) and add the modifier `public` before the keyword `class`. A remark on your format: class names should always start with an uppercase character: `oneClass` -> `OneClass`

Comment: @Turing85, That is what I am doing but is there not another option to initilize the `otuerclass`? Seems quite inconvenient.

Comment: The "inner class" (which is not really inner, just an additional class in a file) has [default visibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and is thus not visible from other packages. You cannot set the visibility of the second class to `public` since only one class per file is allowed to be `public`, and this class must have the same name as the file it resides in.

Comment: @Turing85, Even protected is not allowed.

Comment: Well... protected does not make sense in this context =) how would you derive from a class that is in another package, if you cannot see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Turing85 pointed out the `oneClass` should be in it's own file, otherwise it's going to be `package-private` which means you can only access it from classes of the same package.

Is there another way? There is, but it's not going to be a simple constructor call. Using reflection you can bypass class, field and method invocation protection.

```
public class InnerClassTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Constructor<OneClass> constructor = OneClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        OneClass instance = constructor.newInstance("John");
        InnerClass innerClass = new InnerClass(1, instance);
    }
}
```

What this does is that it finds the constructor that is private to Main because the class is package-private. Then it disables the protection of it, note that these are temporary, the Constructor object is a new reference and only allows the invocation via this reference.

But **I don't recommend doing this** extensively. Reflection has some use cases, mainly to aid programmers in frameworks like Spring, but otherwise it can break object oriented patterns.